# what does $1 in .htaccess file mean?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to understand the meaning of this line in the .htaccess file

```
 RewriteRule ([a-z0-9/-]+).html $1.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

basically what does $1.php ? what file in the server

if we have home.html where this gonna redirect to? home.php?

Comment: $1 matches what's returned from the regular expression match from  the brackets on the left

Comment: @Kabamaru **$1** not *$*

Comment: so if we have home.html? what does that mean? or what php file I would be looking for

Comment: if someone goes to `home.html`, they would be taken to `home.php`

Answer (score 23):

`$1` is the first captured group from your regular expression; that is, the contents between `(` and `)`. If you had a second set of parentheses in your regex, `$2` would contain the contents of those parens. Here is an example:

```
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9/-]+)-([a-z]+).html$ $1-$2.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Say a user navigates to `hello-there.html`. They would be served `hello-there.php`. In your substitution string, `$1` contains the contents of the first set of parens (`hello`), while `$2` contains the contents of the second set (`there`). There will always be exactly as many "dollar" values available in your substitution string as there are sets of capturing parentheses in your regex.

If you have nested parens, say, `(([a-z]+)-[a-z]+)`, `$1` always refers to the *outermost* capture (in this case the whole regex), `$2` is the first *nested* set, and so on.

Comment: As a minor point here, since there is no `R` flag, this won't really "redirect" to that page; the rewrite will happen entirely internally. It is more accurate to say that a user navigating to `hello-there.html` will *be served* `hello-there.php`; they will have no way of knowing that's what happened.

Answer (score 5):

`.htaccess` files can contain a wide variety of Apache configuration directives, but this one, like many, is to do with the URL rewriting module, [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

A [`RewriteRule` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) has 3 parts:

- a Pattern (regular expression) which needs to match against the current URL
- a Substitution string, representing the URL to serve instead, or instruct the browser to redirect to
- an optional set of flags

In this case, you have a regular expression which matches anything ending in `.html` which consists only of letters `a-z`, digits `0-9`, `/` and `-`. However, it also contains a set of parentheses `(...)`, which mark a part of the pattern to be "captured".

The Substitution string can then reference this "captured" value; the first capture is `$1`, and the second would be `$2`, and so on.

In this case, the captured part is everything before the `.html`, and the Substitution is `$1.php`, meaning whatever string came before `.html` is kept, but the `.html` is thrown away and `.php` is stuck on instead.

So for your specific example, accessing `home.html` will instead act as though you had requested `home.php`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a reference to the first capture group denoted by the parentheses in the pattern `([a-z0-9/-]+).html$`.  If there were two `(.*)-(.*)` then you would access `$1` for the first capture group and `$2` for the second, etc...

Answer (score 2):

`$1` refers to **the first group caught** by your regex (ie between parenthesis). In your case it refers to :

```
([a-z0-9/-]+)
```

For the URL `mypage.html`, `$1` will contain "mypage", and the rule will redirect to `mypage.php`.

Comment: This rule concretely means "if URL is mypage.html, load mypage.php". It will work for **any** URL which contains only letters, digits, slashes and dashed (and followed by `.html`)